# How do you test the logic inside _app.js in next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I make a list of request to fetch configs in my getInitialProps and I want to write tests to ensure those calls are made. Trying mount the _app.js file in the test doesn't work and I don't want to simply render it using a webdriver to check if the html is rendered properly. Any suggestions?

Comment: `I don't want to simply render it`... Why not? If it renders on a test it should render on _app.js. That's how you run tests. You mock them

Comment: When you render via webdriver you cannot test if a certain function you are spying on in the componentDidMount was called. _app is essentially an extension of a react component, so I should be able to mount it using enzyme but it does not mount and that is the issue I am trying to get around. Not sure what you mean by ` If it renders on a test it should render on _app.js. `.

Comment: If you want to test the content of your `getInitialProps` method, make it a function and test it like a normal function (unit, with mocks, etc). However, if you want to test that `getInitialProps` is called when you render your app, then you are testing that NextJS is behaving properly and you should not do this test because it's in the scope of NextJS contract with you (the user). Finally if you want to ensure that your app is working at any point in time, then you should indeed render it with any webdriver-based tool (cypress, cucumber, etc)